# AngularJS promise error parsing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying start with promises win angularJS.

But, I am getting an error when AngularJS is parsing the result from the backend.

What is wrong here?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="clinang" ng-controller="pacientesCtrl">
     <a class='btn btnprimary' href='/getdadospac/?oper=S' >Button</a> 
     <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="paciente in $data">
            <td title="'Pront'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'pront'">
                {{paciente.pront}}</td>
            <td title="'Nome'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'nome'">
                {{paciente.nome}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Here is my JSON data returning from the backend:

```
{"draw":,"recordsTotal":5303,"recordsFiltered":5303,
"data":[{"DT_RowId":"4367","pront":"4367","nome":"XXXXXXXXX","endereco":"RUA TEODORO DA SILVA,294\/314","bairro":"VILA ISABEL","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"2567*0440","cpf":"","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"21","pront":"21","nome":"YYYYYYYYY","endereco":"R ARAGUAIA","bairro":"PARQUE CHUNO","cidade":"DUQUE DE CAXIAS","estado":"RJ","telefone":"35637685","cpf":"02570293709","email":"jaceni@ig.com.br"},
{"DT_RowId":"23","pront":"23","nome":"ZZZZZZZZZZ","endereco":"rua 18 de outubro 241 101","bairro":"tijuca","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"","cpf":"","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"24","pront":"24","nome":"AAAAAAAAAAA","endereco":"RUA MARIZ E BARROS 470 APTO 610","bairro":"TIJUCA","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"22646701","cpf":"53551192715","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"27","pront":"27","nome":"AAAAAAAA GON\u00C7ALVES","endereco":"rua an\u00E1polis 251","bairro":"nova igua\u00E7u","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"3101-9648","cpf":"","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"28","pront":"28","nome":"ASKLJALDJSLKADJ","endereco":"lucio de mendon\u00E7a 24 apt 501","bairro":"maracana","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"2568-9519","cpf":"04301072772","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"30","pront":"30","nome":"SADFSADFASDFSD","endereco":"RUA GRAVATAI N 61 APTO 302","bairro":"ROCHA MIRANDA","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"32787747","cpf":"","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"29","pront":"29","nome":"ANASADFSA DOS SANTOS","endereco":"saboia lima 12 apt 04","bairro":"tijuca","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"2204-1498","cpf":"48080152268","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"31","pront":"31","nome":"JOAO SDAFSA SOUZA","endereco":"av dom helder camara 312 bl 05 apt 102","bairro":"benfica","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"","cpf":"075422437-64","email":""},
{"DT_RowId":"33","pront":"33","nome":"SKDJFSDAJFLASD","endereco":"fabio da luz 275 bl 04 apt 504","bairro":"meier","cidade":"RIO DE JANEIRO","estado":"RJ","telefone":"3979-0859","cpf":"","email":""}]}
```

I am getting the next error in my JSON return:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 8
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson (http://127.0.0.1:8888/files/lib/angular/angular.js:1377:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://127.0.0.1:8888/files/lib/angular/angular.js:11003:16)
```

JS CODE:

```
var app = angular.module("clinang", ["ngTable", "ngResource"]);
            (function() {

              app.controller("pacientesCtrl", pacientesCtrl);
              pacientesCtrl.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$resource"];

              function pacientesCtrl(NgTableParams, $resource) {
                // tip: to debug, open chrome dev tools and uncomment the following line 
                debugger;

                var Api = $resource("/getdadospac/?oper=S");
                this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                  getData: function(params) {
                    // ajax request to api
                    return Api.get(params.url())
                      .$promise
                      .then(function(rows) {
                          debugger;
                          console.log(rows);    
                          params.total(rows.recordsTotal); // recal. page nav controls
                          return rows.data;
                    });
                  }
                });
                 this.tableParams.reload();
              }
            })();
```

Comment: There is no value returned against "draw". That is why the error is occurring. Add null to response and it will be fixed.

Comment: your JSON is wrong: `"draw":, `

Comment: Thanks  to all. I am a stupid. I didn´t see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the JSON is invalid. Specifically, on the first line:

```
{"draw":,"recordsTotal":5303, .....
```

The `"draw"` member does not have a value.
You can test your JSON using a linter like [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Comment: Thank you, I just put the value into draw in the backend. It solves the error. I stiil have a problem. My html view is not showing the data. Can you tell me what is wrong in the html?

Comment: Hey @LuizAlves , glad it help you out. I'm not familiar with the ngTable directive, hence I'm not sure what could be wrong with that. You may want to ask a different question specific to the ngTable issue.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response is invalid so the parsing fails. The key "draw" does not have a value, thus the invalid character at position 8 error.

You can read more about valid JSON objects here:
http://json-schema.org

Some examples here:
http://json-schema.org/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a JSON validator it shows that there is an error in the JSON format you are getting back

Error: Parse error on line 1:

"draw": ,"recordsTotal": 
------^

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

You need to look at the construction of the object from the backend

Comment: In response to your html not showing your data, make sure you are setting the scope to the returned data